# Configure Visual Studio 2008 to compile Posix applications

Tags: windows, visual-studio, posix

I'm an experienced programmer in .Net languages but I have not almost any work experience in C++ or C development.

I currently have to develop an application for a device running VxWorks (a realtime OS). We will first build a x86 version and then port to VxWorks. As VxWorks is Posix compliant we plan to create a Posix application in Windows. As I've been reading Windows is not Posix compliant to I installed "Windows Services for UNIX".

Now I'm a bit lost, I suspect that I have to configure Visual Studio to compile using the Posix libraries and headers included in "Windows Services for UNIX" but I really don't know how. And maybe I'm understanding wrong how to develop Posix applications for x86.

Any hints would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Did not do it try it by myself, but since [SFU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_Services_for_UNIX) contains primarily command line tools, including compiler and debugger, IMHO you have to write classical, handcoded makefiles for your project build. Visual Studio has a project type "Makefile project", where you can configure which [make](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29#Modern_versions) utility to use. Default will be *nmake*, but I am sure you can replace this by *gmake* that is part of SFU. If you don't have experience with "make", give Google a try with "make tutorial", finds you, for example,  [this one](http://www.eng.hawaii.edu/Tutor/Make/).

Comment: Thanks, but the main problem is how to tell the Visual Studio to use the Posix libraries supplied by the SFU.

Comment: When using Makefiles, you typically will specify the libraries as command line parameters to your command line compiler. Not "Visual Studio" needs the libraries, your compiler does. In fact, don't expect "Visual Studio" to be more than a smart text editor in this scenario.